# Instancing millions of objects in OpenGL: improving frames-per-second

Tags: c++, opengl, render, geometry-instancing

My ultimate goal is to render 1 million spheres of different sizes and colors at 60 fps.  I want to be able to move the camera around the screen as well.

I have modified the code on [this page of the tutorial I am studying](http://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing) to try to instance many spheres.  However, I find that at as little as 64 spheres my fps falls below 60, and at 900 spheres my fps is a measly 4.  My understanding of instancing is naive, but I believe that I should be getting more frames-per-second than this.  60 fps should be attainable with only 64 spheres.  I believe that I am, in some way, causing the CPU and GPU to communicate more often than they should have to.  So my question is: How do I instance so many objects (ideally millions) without causing the fps to fall low (ideally 60 fps)?

I am calculating fps by calculating `(10 / time_elapsed)` every 10 frames, where `time_elapsed` is the time that has elapsed since the last fps call.  I am printing this out using `printf` on line 118 of my code.

I have been learning OpenGL through [this tutorial](http://www.learnopengl.com/) and so I use [32-bit GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) and [32-bit GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) in Visual Studio 2013.  I have 8 GB of RAM on a 64-bit operating system (Windows 7) with a [2.30 GHz CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/85213/Intel-Core-i5-5300U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_90-GHz).

I have tried coding my own example based on the tutorial above.  Source code:

(set line #2 to be the number of spheres to be instanced. Make sure line#2 has a whole-number square root.  Set line 4 to be the detail of the sphere, the lowest it can go is 0.  Higher number = more detailed.)

```
// Make sure NUM_INS is a square number
#define NUM_INS 1

// Detail up to 4 is probably good enough
#define SPHERE_DETAIL 4

#include <vector>

// GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

// GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

// GL includes
#include "Shader.h"

// GLM Mathemtics
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

// Properties
GLuint screenWidth = 800, screenHeight = 600;

// Function prototypes
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);
std::vector<GLfloat> create_sphere(int recursion);

// The MAIN function, from here we start our application and run the Game loop
int main()
{
  // Init GLFW
  glfwInit();
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

  GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "LearnOpenGL", nullptr, nullptr); // Windowed
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

  // Set the required callback functions
  glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

  // Initialize GLEW to setup the OpenGL Function pointers
  glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
  glewInit();

  // Define the viewport dimensions
  glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
  glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE); // Comment to remove wireframe mode

  // Setup OpenGL options
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  // Setup and compile our shader(s)
  Shader shader("core.vs", "core.frag");

  // Generate a list of 100 quad locations/translation-vectors
  std::vector<glm::vec2> translations(NUM_INS);
  //glm::vec2 translations[NUM_INS];
  int index = 0;
  GLfloat offset = 1.0f / (float)sqrt(NUM_INS);
  for (GLint y = -(float)sqrt(NUM_INS); y < (float)sqrt(NUM_INS); y += 2)
  {
    for (GLint x = -(float)sqrt(NUM_INS); x < (float)sqrt(NUM_INS); x += 2)
    {
      glm::vec2 translation;
      translation.x = (GLfloat)x / (float)sqrt(NUM_INS) + offset;
      translation.y = (GLfloat)y / (float)sqrt(NUM_INS) + offset;
      translations[index++] = translation;
    }
  }

  // Store instance data in an array buffer
  GLuint instanceVBO;
  glGenBuffers(1, &instanceVBO);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceVBO);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec2) * NUM_INS, &translations[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

  // create 12 vertices of a icosahedron
  std::vector<GLfloat> vv = create_sphere(SPHERE_DETAIL);

  GLuint quadVAO, quadVBO;
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &quadVAO);
  glGenBuffers(1, &quadVBO);
  glBindVertexArray(quadVAO);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quadVBO);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vv.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), &vv[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
  glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
  // Also set instance data
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceVBO);
  glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
  glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 1); // Tell OpenGL this is an instanced vertex attribute.
  glBindVertexArray(0);

  // For printing frames-per-second
  float counter = 0;
  double get_time = 0;
  double new_time;

  // Game loop
  while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
  {
    // Print fps by printing (number_of_frames / time_elapsed)
    counter += 1;
    if (counter > 10) {
      counter -= 10;
      new_time = glfwGetTime();
      printf("fps: %.2f ", (10/(new_time - get_time)));
      get_time = new_time;
    }

    // Check and call events
    glfwPollEvents();

    // Clear buffers
    //glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Draw 100 instanced quads
    shader.Use();

    glm::mat4 model;
    model = glm::rotate(model, 0.0f, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    // Camera/View transformation
    glm::mat4 view;
    GLfloat radius = 10.0f;
    GLfloat camX = sin(glfwGetTime()) * radius;
    GLfloat camZ = cos(glfwGetTime()) * radius;
    view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(camX, 0.0f, camZ), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    // Projection 
    glm::mat4 projection;
    projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)screenWidth / (GLfloat)screenHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    // Get the uniform locations
    GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "model");
    GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "view");
    GLint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "projection");
    // Pass the matrices to the shader
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

    glBindVertexArray(quadVAO);
    glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vv.size() / 3, NUM_INS); // 100 triangles of 6 vertices each
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // Swap the buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
  }

  glfwTerminate();
  return 0;
}

// Is called whenever a key is pressed/released via GLFW
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
  if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}

std::vector<GLfloat> add_color(std::vector<GLfloat> sphere) {
  // Add color
  std::vector<GLfloat> colored_sphere;
  for (GLint i = 0; i < sphere.size(); i+=9) {
    colored_sphere.push_back(sphere[i]);
    colored_sphere.push_back(sphere[i+1]);
    colored_sphere.push_back(sphere[i+2]);
    colored_sphere.push_back(0.0f);
    colored_sphere.push_back(0.0f);
    colored_sphere.push_back(0.0f);
    colored_sphere.push_back(sphere[i+3]);
    colored_sphere.push_back(sphere[i+4]);
    colored_sphere.push_back(sphere[i+5]);
    colored_sphere.push_back(0.0f);
    colored_sphere.push_back(0.0f);
    colored_sphere.push_back(0.0f);
    colored_sphere.push_back(sphere[i+6]);
    colored_sphere.push_back(sphere[i+7]);
    colored_sphere.push_back(sphere[i+8]);
    colored_sphere.push_back(0.0f);
    colored_sphere.push_back(0.0f);
    colored_sphere.push_back(0.0f);
  }

  return colored_sphere;
}

std::vector<GLfloat> tesselate(std::vector<GLfloat> shape, int recursion) {

  if (recursion > 0) {
    std::vector<GLfloat> new_sphere = {};
    for (GLint i = 0; i < shape.size(); i += 9) {

      // 1.902113 approximately
      GLfloat radius = sqrt(1.0f + pow((1.0f + sqrt(5.0f)) / 2.0f, 2));

      // Every 9 points is a triangle.  Take 1 triangle and turn it into 4 triangles.  
      GLfloat p_one[] = {shape[i], shape[i + 1], shape[i + 2]};
      GLfloat p_two[] = {shape[i + 3], shape[i + 4], shape[i + 5]};
      GLfloat p_thr[] = {shape[i + 6], shape[i + 7], shape[i + 8]};
      GLfloat p_one_two[] = { (p_one[0] + p_two[0]) / 2.0f, (p_one[1] + p_two[1]) / 2.0f, (p_one[2] + p_two[2]) / 2.0f };
      GLfloat p_one_thr[] = { (p_one[0] + p_thr[0]) / 2.0f, (p_one[1] + p_thr[1]) / 2.0f, (p_one[2] + p_thr[2]) / 2.0f };
      GLfloat p_two_thr[] = { (p_two[0] + p_thr[0]) / 2.0f, (p_two[1] + p_thr[1]) / 2.0f, (p_two[2] + p_thr[2]) / 2.0f };

      GLfloat r_one_two = sqrt((p_one_two[0]*p_one_two[0]) + (p_one_two[1]*p_one_two[1]) + (p_one_two[2]*p_one_two[2]));
      GLfloat r_one_thr = sqrt((p_one_thr[0]*p_one_thr[0]) + (p_one_thr[1]*p_one_thr[1]) + (p_one_thr[2]*p_one_thr[2]));
      GLfloat r_two_thr = sqrt((p_two_thr[0]*p_two_thr[0]) + (p_two_thr[1]*p_two_thr[1]) + (p_two_thr[2]*p_two_thr[2]));

      GLfloat t_one_two[] = { radius * p_one_two[0] / r_one_two, radius * p_one_two[1] / r_one_two, radius * p_one_two[2] / r_one_two };
      GLfloat t_one_thr[] = { radius * p_one_thr[0] / r_one_thr, radius * p_one_thr[1] / r_one_thr, radius * p_one_thr[2] / r_one_thr };
      GLfloat t_two_thr[] = { radius * p_two_thr[0] / r_two_thr, radius * p_two_thr[1] / r_two_thr, radius * p_two_thr[2] / r_two_thr };

      // Triangle 1:
        new_sphere.push_back(p_one[0]);
      new_sphere.push_back(p_one[1]);
      new_sphere.push_back(p_one[2]);

      new_sphere.push_back(t_one_two[0]);
      new_sphere.push_back(t_one_two[1]);
      new_sphere.push_back(t_one_two[2]);

      new_sphere.push_back(t_one_thr[0]);
      new_sphere.push_back(t_one_thr[1]);
      new_sphere.push_back(t_one_thr[2]);

      // Triangle 2:
        new_sphere.push_back(p_two[0]);
      new_sphere.push_back(p_two[1]);
      new_sphere.push_back(p_two[2]);

      new_sphere.push_back(t_one_two[0]);
      new_sphere.push_back(t_one_two[1]);
      new_sphere.push_back(t_one_two[2]);

      new_sphere.push_back(t_two_thr[0]);
      new_sphere.push_back(t_two_thr[1]);
      new_sphere.push_back(t_two_thr[2]);

      // Triangle 3: 
        new_sphere.push_back(p_thr[0]);
      new_sphere.push_back(p_thr[1]);
      new_sphere.push_back(p_thr[2]);

      new_sphere.push_back(t_one_thr[0]);
      new_sphere.push_back(t_one_thr[1]);
      new_sphere.push_back(t_one_thr[2]);

      new_sphere.push_back(t_two_thr[0]);
      new_sphere.push_back(t_two_thr[1]);
      new_sphere.push_back(t_two_thr[2]);

      // Center Triangle:

        new_sphere.push_back(t_one_two[0]);
      new_sphere.push_back(t_one_two[1]);
      new_sphere.push_back(t_one_two[2]);

      new_sphere.push_back(t_one_thr[0]);
      new_sphere.push_back(t_one_thr[1]);
      new_sphere.push_back(t_one_thr[2]);

      new_sphere.push_back(t_two_thr[0]);
      new_sphere.push_back(t_two_thr[1]);
      new_sphere.push_back(t_two_thr[2]);
    }
    return tesselate(new_sphere, recursion - 1);
  }

  printf("number of vertices to be rendered: %d || ", shape.size());
  return shape;
}

std::vector<GLfloat> create_sphere(int recursion) {

  // Define the starting icosahedron
  GLfloat t_ = (1.0f + sqrt(5.0f)) / 2.0f;

  std::vector<GLfloat> icosahedron = {
    -1.0f,  t_,  0.0f, -t_,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  t_,
    -1.0f,  t_,  0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  t_, 1.0f,  t_,  0.0f,
    -1.0f,  t_,  0.0f, 1.0f,  t_,  0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, -t_,
    -1.0f,  t_,  0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, -t_, -t_,  0.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  t_,  0.0f, -t_,  0.0f, -1.0f, -t_,  0.0f,  1.0f,

    1.0f,  t_,  0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  t_,  t_,  0.0f,  1.0f, 
    0.0f,  1.0f,  t_, -t_,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  t_, 
    -t_,  0.0f,  1.0f, -t_,  0.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -t_,  0.0f, 
    -t_,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, -t_,  0.0f, -1.0f, -t_, 
    0.0f,  1.0f, -t_,  1.0f,  t_,  0.0f,  t_,  0.0f, -1.0f, 

    1.0f, -t_,  0.0f, t_,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  t_,
    1.0f, -t_,  0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  t_,-1.0f, -t_,  0.0f,
    1.0f, -t_,  0.0f,-1.0f, -t_,  0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, -t_,
    1.0f, -t_,  0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, -t_, t_,  0.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -t_,  0.0f, t_,  0.0f, -1.0f, t_,  0.0f,  1.0f,

    0.0f, -1.0f,  t_, t_,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  t_,
    -1.0f, -t_,  0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  t_,-t_,  0.0f,  1.0f,
    0.0f, -1.0f, -t_,-1.0f, -t_,  0.0f,-t_,  0.0f, -1.0f,
    t_,  0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, -t_, 0.0f,  1.0f, -t_,
    t_,  0.0f,  1.0f, t_,  0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  t_,  0.0f,
  };

  // Tesselate the icososphere the number of times recursion
  std::vector<GLfloat> colorless_sphere = tesselate(icosahedron, recursion);

  // Add color and return
  return add_color(colorless_sphere);
}
```

Vertex Shader: (named core.vs)

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 offset;

out vec3 fColor;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
  gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position.x + offset.x, position.y + offset.y, position.z, 1.0f);
  fColor = color;
}
```

Fragment Shader: (named core.frag)

```
#version 330 core
in vec3 fColor;
out vec4 color;

void main()
{
  color = vec4(fColor, 1.0f);
}
```

Shader class: (named Shader.h)

```
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>

class Shader
{
  public:
  GLuint Program;
  // Constructor generates the shader on the fly
  Shader(const GLchar* vertexPath, const GLchar* fragmentPath)
  {
    // 1. Retrieve the vertex/fragment source code from filePath
    std::string vertexCode;
    std::string fragmentCode;
    std::ifstream vShaderFile;
    std::ifstream fShaderFile;
    // ensures ifstream objects can throw exceptions:
      vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);
    fShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);
    try
    {
      // Open files
      vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
      fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
      std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
      // Read file's buffer contents into streams
      vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
      fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();
      // close file handlers
      vShaderFile.close();
      fShaderFile.close();
      // Convert stream into string
      vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
      fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
    }
      catch (std::ifstream::failure e)
      {
      std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ" << std::endl;
      }
      const GLchar* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
      const GLchar * fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();
      // 2. Compile shaders
      GLuint vertex, fragment;
      GLint success;
      GLchar infoLog[512];
      // Vertex Shader
      vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
      glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
      glCompileShader(vertex);
      // Print compile errors if any
      glGetShaderiv(vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
      if (!success)
      {
      glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex, 512, NULL, infoLog);
      std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
      }
      // Fragment Shader
      fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
      glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
      glCompileShader(fragment);
      // Print compile errors if any
      glGetShaderiv(fragment, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
      if (!success)
      {
      glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment, 512, NULL, infoLog);
      std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
      }
      // Shader Program
      this->Program = glCreateProgram();
      glAttachShader(this->Program, vertex);
      glAttachShader(this->Program, fragment);
      glLinkProgram(this->Program);
      // Print linking errors if any
      glGetProgramiv(this->Program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
      if (!success)
      {
      glGetProgramInfoLog(this->Program, 512, NULL, infoLog);
      std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
      }
      // Delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessery
      glDeleteShader(vertex);
      glDeleteShader(fragment);

  }
    // Uses the current shader
    void Use()
    {
      glUseProgram(this->Program);
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: probably insignificant but you could compute `(float)sqrt(NUM_INS)` once and for all (the CPU will say thanks).

Comment: this helped med do instanced rendering: http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial33/tutorial33.html Its just a different draw call that tells the gpu to recycle information already sent

Comment: What class of hardware are you targeting out of curiosity? You could always take the opportunity to learn about compute shaders and indirect draw :) Generate all of those instances completely GPU-side and things will fly.

Comment: @Charlie Maybe I didn't mention in my post, but I am already using instancing in my code.  This is why my results confuse me.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I am targeting computers with my same hardware, or maybe slightly worse.

Comment: The gpu you are using would be the interesting thing here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My ultimate goal is to render 1 million spheres of different sizes and colors at 60 fps.

This is an unreasonable expectation.

Let's say that each sphere consists of 50 triangles. Kinda small for a good sphere shape, but lets assume they're that small.

1 million spheres at 50 tris per sphere is 50 million triangles *per frame*. At 60 FPS, that's 3 *billion* triangles per second.

No commercially available GPU is good enough to do that. And that's just a 50 triangle sphere; your 4x tessellated icosahedron will be over *5,000* triangles.

Now yes, drawing 60 such spheres is only ~300,000 triangles per frame. But even that at 60 FPS is ~18 million triangles per second. Hardware does exist that can handle that many triangles, but it's very clearly a *lot*. And you're *definitely* not going to get 1 million of them.

This is not a matter of GPU/CPU communication or overhead. You're simply throwing more work at your GPU than it could handle. You might be able to improve a couple of things here and there, but nothing that's going to get you even one tenth of what you want.

At least, not with this overall approach.

---

For your particular case of wanting to draw millions of spheres, I would use raytraced impostors rather than actual geometry of spheres. That is, you draw quads, who's positions are generated by the vertex (or geometry) shader. You generate a quad per sphere, such that the quad circumscribes the sphere. Then the fragment shader does a simple ray-sphere intersection test to see if the fragment in question (from the direction of the camera view) hits the sphere or not. If the ray doesn't hit the sphere, you discard the fragment.

You would also need to modify `gl_FragDepth` to give the impostor the proper depth value, so that intersecting spheres can work.

Comment: Maybe you're right that millions of spheres is too ambitious.  However, here is a video where half-a-million spheres are rendered in OpenGL where they move and stuff too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tnc_IoXwH24  Maybe I have to modify my project to meet your criteria, or a lower fps as in this video.

Comment: @PaulTerwilliger: Did you read the details on that video? Specifically, the part where it says "The number of triangles used for each sphere depends on it's distance from the viewer." That rules instancing out as a tool.

Comment: I see, so is there no way that you know of to use instancing for different details of spheres?  Couldn't I send spheres of different details to the GPU and then render some or others depending on distance?

Comment: @PaulTerwilliger: Why are you so hung up on using instancing? Could you have several different sphere resolutions, then sort your instances based on distance to the camera? But the video in question is *not* doing that; it's *generating* vertex data on the GPU.

Comment: I'm not hung up on instancing, I just thought that instancing was THE method of drawing many of the same object.  I'm learning and it's the only thing I was able to read about.  If there are other methods, like the one you posted about, and they work for my goals, then I would love to use those.  My only goals are to render lots of spheres (hundreds of thousands minimum)

Comment: @PaulTerwilliger: "*I just thought that instancing was THE method of drawing many of the same object*" It is. But they're not "the same object" if they have different triangle counts.